# Get username and Emailaddress from OAuth login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, oauth

In our MVC4 application we have a working OAuth registering system (this was quite easy to implement in MVC4 because of all the standard code). Users can login via Google and then they are redirected to our ExternalLoginConfirmation view with an ExternalLoginConfirmation controller.

We have a User Model which looks like this:

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

We also have the standard RegisterExternalLoginModel which looks like this:

```
public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is mandatory.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
}
```

The code below is the code we use in the ExternalLoginConfirmation controller and accomplishes that the user is also put into our User Model:

```
// POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, 
     string returnUrl)
{
    string provider = null;
    string providerUserId = null;

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||    
       !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.
       ExternalLoginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Manage");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Insert a new user into the database
        using ( [project]Context db = new [project]Context())
        {
            User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name.ToLower() == 
                 model.UserName.ToLower());
         // Check if user already exists
             if (user == null)
             {
              // Insert name into the profile table
                    user = new User { Name = model.UserName, isAvailable = true };
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();                   

                    OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, 
                          providerUserId, model.UserName);
                    OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, 
                            createPersistentCookie: false);

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
              }
              else
              {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Username already exists")
              }
          }
      }

      ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = 
              OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;
              ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
      return View(model);
 }
```

The view looks like this:

```
@model Models.RegisterExternalLoginModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account", 
      new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
       {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


           <!-- This does not work and displays the e-mailaddress instead of
                "full name" -->

               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", 
                      @placeholder = "Full name" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

            <!-- Here we want extra code to grab the e-mailaddress from the user -->


           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ExternalLoginData)
           <button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
       }
```

This puts the user with the chosen Username and an isAvailable property of true in the database.

The issues we have with this code are (1) that the Username that is displayed in the TextBoxFor in the view is the e-mailaddress of the person that logs in instead of the "full name" property (no idea why). (2) We want an e-mailaddress attribute that *does* automatically display the e-mailaddress (or even better an hidden field that just takes this information and brings it to the controller). And (3) we want the controller to add the user with his chosen userName (full name) and E-mailaddress into the Users table of the database.

Unfortunately we are new to C# and MVC and have no idea how to accomplish this. We hope someone can give us some advice on this!

Best wishes

Comment: Isn't it inside `ExternalLoginData`? You might need to write your own parser for that to extract all the info you need

Comment: You mean the string ExternalLoginData? The string ExternalLoginData consists of a string of hexadecimal numbers like this: "F1B54638F16A35A5F0 [et cetera]". So I have no idea how to use that. Do you know where I can learn to write my own parser? Or is there perhaps another way? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ah yes, it's encrypted. You need to get at the `AuthenticationResult` object. Does this help? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc